# Not sure why my laravel if code is crashing my wordpress site. Not sure if there is a syntax issue here

Tags: laravel, wordpress

All I am trying to do is to display a different phone number as long as the page doesn't have the slug 'espanol-template'. Not exactly sure whats wrong with my if code.

```
  <a class="phoneColor  display-4 " href="tel:8017580512">
  @php
    @if(!is_page('espanol-template'))
      {{ $global_acf -> phone_Number }}
    @else
    echo '(801) 871-8263';
    @endif
  @endphp
  </a>
```

Comment: This code is not "Laravel" code, it is `.blade` templating. Is your file a `.blade.php` file? Can Wordpress even use blade templating? Why not just use regular php? `<?php if (...) { ?>` instead of `@if`, `<?php echo $global_acf->phone_number; ?>` instead of `{{ ... }}`, etc.

Comment: Gotcha, yes it is a .blade.php and yes Wordpress can use blade templating when using sage theme from roots.io which is a theme starter.  I don't fully recommend it since it makes things a little more complicated.

Comment: Makes sense! I was pretty sure you could use `blade` templating anywhere, i.e. it's not exclusive to Laravel, but I hadn't heard of using it in Wordpress. That might make wp development actually somewhat bearable, but that's a separate point. So, if `blade` is available, then you code would be `@if(!is_page('espanol-template')) {{ $global_acf->phone_Number }} @else {{ '(801) 871-8263' }} @endif`; no need for `@php` and `@endphp` at all; `@if` opens a PHP block as well.

Comment: Ooooh i thought you needed those @php there but I guess not. That solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: No problem! Just be aware of the equivalents: `@php ... @endphp` is the same as `<?php ... ?>`, `@if ... @endif` is the same as `<?php if(...) { ... } ?>`, and `{{ ... }}` is equivalent to `<?php echo ...; ?>`. Your code was basically `<?php <?php if ... ` which, for obvious reasons once broken down, won't compile correctly. Glad you got it working! Cheers 